# how to fix NameError: name 'label' is not defined in tkinter app any assistance will be highly appreciated, Thanks

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

when I click the reset button

```
def clear_text():
    my_text_box.delete("1.0","end") 
    entry1.delete(0, END)
    entry2.delete(0, END)
    previous_selected = list.curselection()
    if list.curselection() == previous_selected:
        list.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
    if label3.winfo_exists() == 1:
        label3.destroy()
    if label4.winfo_exists() == 1:
        label4.destroy()      
    
button = tk.Button(text='Reset', command=clear_text, bg='black', fg='yellow', activebackground='blue', activeforeground='white', font=('consolas', 14, 'bold')) 
button.grid(row=6, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
```

It clears a few things, however, there is an error displayed in the terminal.

```
nameerror: name 'label3' is not defined exception in tkinter callback traceback (most recent call last): file "c:\users\zubairi\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__ return self.func(*args) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ file "c:\users\zubairi\desktop\final_call_script.py", line 189, in clear_text if label3.winfo_exists() == 1:.
```

the label3 is created by clicking another button which is linked to the below mentioned function:

```
def min_installment():
    global x1
    x1 = entry1.get()
    global y1
    y1 = entry2.get()
    global label3
    label3 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=window, text = 'In order to settle the balance of R' + str(x1) + ' within ' + y1 + ' months, pay at least:', font=('arial', 21, 'bold'))
    label3.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    global label4
    label4 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=window, text='R '+str('%.2f' %((float(x1) * 1.08) / float(y1)))+' pm', font=('arial', 21, 'bold')) 
    label4.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=10, pady=7)

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=window, width=120, height=40, border_width=0, corner_radius=20, text="Caculate", command=min_installment)
button.grid(row=6, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
```

I hope this makes sense, God Bless!!

Comment: Is `min_installment` being called before `clear_text`? If not, `label3` won't exist when `clear_text` is called

Comment: the min_installment is the function that creates the label, however, I think the reset button is causing the error

Comment: there will be times that the reset button will be clicked without the label being created, hence the if statement, yet the error is still there

Comment: That's my point. If `min_installment` isn't called before `clear_text`, then `clear_text` will run into an error because `min_installment` never created the label in question

Comment: if label3.winfo_exists() == 1:
        label3.destroy()

Comment: `winfo_exists` will fail if `label3` hasn't been declared. If `clear_text` is called *BEFORE* `min_installment`, then there is no object named `label3` at all. `winfo_exists` doesn't "know" what `label3` is because there's no object by that name - which is why you get a `nameError`.

Comment: what about using a lambda function?

Comment: What about it? How would that help? I don't mean to come across as flippant, but `lambda`s won't do you any good here.

Comment: thank you Mr Riggles, All the best to you and your family. I think I understand now.

Comment: Happy to help - if the answer below works out for you, don't forget to mark it as "accepted" so that others know this question has been answered. If not, leave a comment and I'll do my best to edit anything that's not working / isn't clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the `nameError` you're getting from `label3` (and would also get from `label4` if it ever got that far), you can declare the two labels in the global scope and then all `min_installment` needs to do is add them to the `grid` after the fact, and use `configure()` to update their text appropriately.

You likely also want to use `grid_forget()` on the labels instead of `destroy()` so then can be put back if needed.

Lastly, you (as far as I can tell) don't need the `global`s here for `x1`, `x2` or the labels.

```
# instantiate the labels outside the functions (in the global scope)
label3 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=window, font=('arial', 21, 'bold'))
label4 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=window, font=('arial', 21, 'bold'))


def clear_text():
    my_text_box.delete("1.0","end") 
    entry1.delete(0, END)
    entry2.delete(0, END)
    previous_selected = list.curselection()
    if list.curselection() == previous_selected:
        list.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
    if label3.winfo_exists():
        label3.destroy()
    if label4.winfo_exists():
        label4.destroy() 


def min_installment():
    x1 = entry1.get()
    y1 = entry2.get()

    label3.configure(text = 'In order to settle the balance of R' + x1 + ' within ' + y1 + ' months, pay at least:')
    label3.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    label4.configure(text='R ' + str('%.2f' %((float(x1) * 1.08) / float(y1))) + ' pm') 
    label4.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=10, pady=7)
```

*A few edits*

You don't need the `== 1` after `winfo_exists()`, and you don't need `str(x1)` in the `label3.configure` call since that value is already a string at that time